# How to render a Chinese char exactly 2 English chars wide

Tags: wpf

I want to render Chinese chars, **every Chinese char takes 2 English chars width**. I tried Courier New and Segoe UI Mono with and without fallback font SimSun, and didn't succeeded yet. Every-time the app rendered, every Chinese char was a little bit less than 2 English chars in width.

Here is the XAML.

```
<TextBox Name="OUTPUT_cn_TextBox" FontSize="25" 
         Text="{Binding OutputFileCNContent}"
         AcceptsReturn="True" IsReadOnly="True" 
         HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
         FontFamily="Segoe UI Mono, SimSun" 
         FontStretch="ExtraExpanded" />
```

Comment: use Chinese font. `Courier New` and `Segoe UI Mono` are not.

Comment: The fallback font SimSun is actually a Chinese font. So no doubt the app can render Chinese characters. Because I am a new account over Stackoverflow, so I can't post images. Please see my blog for screen shots: sunshaking.blogspot.com

Comment: I don't think this is a question for programming, as what you are looking for is a font that meets the requirements. You should analyze the fonts available or create your own, http://howto.wired.com/wiki/Create_Your_Own_Font

Comment: I think there is a way to render every Chinese char 2 English chars width just as Notepad++ does. Notepad++ doesn't have its own font library. It just use the system fonts. So there must be some tricks to do so. Creating a Chinese font is terrible since there are huge amount of chars in Chinese.

Comment: I think that's a quirk of the font. Some fonts do exactly what you require, like FangSong, KaiTi and MingLiU. You can set VS to use those fonts and you'll what I mean.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li and Camford. I tried YouYuan and it will render a Chinese char matches 2 English chars. But I still wonder how Notepad and Notepad++ do it.

Answer (score 0):

First you should use the a monsopaced font and second set TextFormattingMode to Display